# how to extract the tgz files to another s3 bucket using an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to AWS, and trying to extract tgz files present in s3 bucket and extract it to another s3 bucket using an EC2 instance using python or commands.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

1. aws s3 cp s3://source_bucketname/filename.tgz
2. unzip filename.tgz - lets say it extracts to foldername
3. aws s3 cp --recursive foldername s3://destination_bucketname/

You need not use EC2. You can even use your own PC if you set up aws-cli, its the best way to do this kind of thing.

This is a good reference 
https://qiita.com/alokrawat050/items/56820afdb6968deec6a2

Comment: While true you don't need an EC2 instance for this, if the files are very large then an EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 buckets will make this much faster.

Comment: agree with that